# Invalid use of incomplete type and forward declaration

Tags: c++, qt, forward-declaration

I was trying to resolve this issue but there must be some misunderstanding in how I undestand forward declaration.

I am getting following error:

```
src/algorithm.cpp: In constructor ‘Algorithm::Algorithm(MainWindow*)’:
src/algorithm.cpp:22:20: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Ui::MainWindow’
src/mainwindow.h:23:10: error: forward declaration of ‘struct Ui::MainWindow’
```

I have these files (i ommited some lines and files and pasted only relevant code):

algorithm.cpp

```
#include "algorithm.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

Algorithm::Algorithm(MainWindow *mainWindow)
{
   this->mainWindow = mainWindow;

   QAction *action = new QAction(this);
   action->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("action"));
   action->setText(this->getName());

   mainWindow->m_ui->menuAlgorithms->addAction(action);

   mainWindow->connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(this->start()));
}
```

algorithm.h

```
#ifndef ALGORITHM_H
#define ALGORITHM_H

#include <QObject>

#include "graphwidget.h"
#include "edge.h"
#include "vertex.h"

class MainWindow;

class Algorithm : public QObject
{
public:
   MainWindow *mainWindow;

   Algorithm(MainWindow *mainWindow);

   void start();
   virtual void solve();
   virtual QString getDescription();
   virtual QString getName();
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "algorithm.h"
#include "../ui/ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "vertex.h"
#include "edge.h"
#include "warning.h"

mode_type mode;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
   QMainWindow(parent),
   m_ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   gundirected = NULL;
   gdirected = NULL;

   m_ui->setupUi(this);
...
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QUndoView>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

#include "graphwidget.h"

enum mode_type {NORMAL, VERTEX, EDGE}; // vyctovy typ pro urceni editoacniho modu
extern mode_type mode;

namespace Ui
{
   class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~MainWindow();

   Ui::MainWindow *m_ui;
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're trying to use the `m_ui` member of `MainWindow` class in your `Algorithm` class, and the type of `m_ui` is `Ui::MainWindow`, but your `Algorithm` class is not aware of such type. You can solve this by including the `ui_mainwindow.h` in your `algorithm.cpp`.

But this is still poor design. `m_ui` should be a private member of `MainWindow` class. You should not be accessing it from other classes. Instead create functions in your `MainWindow` class that will allow you to do what you want.

For example, create a public function like this:

```
void MainWindow::addCustomAction(QAction *action)
{
    m_ui->menuAlgorithms->addAction(action);
}
```

Then call this function from your `Algorithm` class:

```
Algorithm::Algorithm(MainWindow *mainWindow)
{
   this->mainWindow = mainWindow;

   QAction *action = new QAction(this);
   action->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("action"));
   action->setText(this->getName());

   mainWindow->addCustomAction(action);

   connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(start()));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your forward declaration appears in namespace `UI`, but your class declaration appears outside  of this namespace. You should change this to

```
 namespace UI {
     class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
         Q_OBJECT
         // ...
     };
 }
```

It also seems you don't need to provide a forward declaration there at all, but change the forward declaration in `Algorithm.h` again to appear `MainWindow` in the right namespace:

```
 namespace UI {
     class MainWindow;
 }
```

Comment: Now I am getting src/main.cpp:15:15: error: aggregate ‘MainWindow window’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
error

Comment: @jb91 You have to specify namespace for your definitions also of course. Either enclose all your definitions in your `.cpp` file with `namespace UI { ... }` or provide a using statement and `using UI::MainWindow;` before all definitions.

Comment: This is not how it should work. `Ui::MainWindow` is not the same as `MainWindow`. `Ui::MainWindow` class is declared in the `ui_mainwindow.h` file. The problem is that he is trying to use `Ui::MainWindow` from `Algorithm` class without including the `ui_mainwindow.h` header.

Comment: @thuga I know that there are more than this flaws in the OP's sample code. I just pointed out what to solve for the foremost one. Feel free to add another answer, going in more depth on the other ore subsequent problems.